# Python Login Multi Solution

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

After reading a lot of articles I came here to ask a question related to flask login with different types of users(two `usermixin classes`).

I have 2 types of users(as mentioned two user classes) - 1.Let’s call them regular users(email and password) 2.Social Network users(Facebook, Twitter, Google) and after a successful `OAuth` login with `Facebook`, `Twitter` and `Google API` I need to disable access to the profile page(regular users have access) and off course to stay logged and log them out later.

Here is the thing, I tried with https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Login-Multi/. Simple, I made 2 blueprints for auth.py where I defined logins for both types of users but it is not working(it crashes when I put `@login_required`)

I can provide my code here but I just want someone to help me with this if possible? Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Flask principal` with roles did the job and one more important thing to say is that I needed to define a login type in the session in order to have a conditional `Flask login` for both types of users(regular and social network).

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between authentication and authorization. Authentication determines who is allowed in and authorization determines what your users are allowed to see.
`@login_required` will handle authentication, but your question as asked deals with authorization. This means you will want to use `@roles_accepted` as well. Create multiple roles based on your intended behavior and then assign these users the appropriate role as needed. Using `@roles_accepted` will then deal with authorization, only allowing authorized users to access that route based on their role.

Comment: I know what is authorization and what is authentication, there is also something called access control(in engineering language said) but I managed to solve this with Flask Principal and wanted to see Flask Login Multi implementation. Regards. @Chase